# What is the equivalent of `if x in y` in hy?

Tags: hy

I can't seem to find a builtin (or equivalent) in hy that lets me check for something without handling an exception

I would like to write something like:

```
(setv foo {:a 1 :b 2})
(if (in foo :c) 
    (foo)  
  (boo))
```

`(:c foo)` and `(get foo :c)` both result in an exception

Answer (score 1):

Hy has an equivalent for all the Python operators. Hy uses prefix notation for all operators, but doesn't change the order of the operands from how they would be in infix notation. So `(- 10 8)` in Hy is `2`, same as `10 - 8` in Python.

This goes for the `in` operator as well. `(in :c foo)` is like `HyKeyword('c') in foo`. Think of it like `in(:c, foo)`, not "In foo, :c?".

Answer (score 0):

instead of (get foo :c) use (.get foo :c) and compare the None if the c keyword does not exist.

```
(setv foo {:a 1 :b 2})
(if (!= (.get foo :c) None) 
    (foo)  
  (boo))
```